# Meaning of the Event $A \cap B$

Tags: probability

The probability of the intersection of events $A$ and $B$ has 2 formulas:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ for independent events,

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B \vert A)$ for dependent events.

There are several things that make me confused. My teacher said intersection events are events that can occur simultaneously and with intersection probability we can calculate the probability of events $A$ and $B$ occurring simultaneously.

But what is meant by happening simultaneously? Is $P(A \cap B)$ something like "the probability that events $A$ and $B$ have the same outcome" or "the probability that events $A$ and $B$ occur at the same time but with no common outcome"?

Comment: In your two displays, you have "dependent" and "independent" swapped.  (If $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(B|A) = P(B)$, so $P(B|A)$ is only interesting in the dependent case.)

Comment: Call event A "card is an ace", and event B "card is a spade". If you deal the ace of spades, both events happen simultaneously.

Comment: Let $A$ be the event that a person has green eyes and let $B$ be the event that a person has brown hair. $A\cap B$ is the event that a person has green eyes and brown hair.

Comment: Thanks for that sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are sets of *possible* outcomes.

We say an event "happens" or "occurs" when the realised outcome is an element of its set.  (Also called the "actual outcome" or just "*the* outcome".)

Two events "occur simultaneously" when the realised outcome is an element of both sets.  That is, it is in their intersection.

So $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ is "the probability for the outcome being an element of both events $A$ and $B$."

Comment: Thanks for that sir

Answer (score 0):

You posted this exact same question yesterday and I gave you the answer in a comment. Perhaps you didn't see it, so I'm making it an actual answer: by using the term "simultaneously", your teacher has misled you into thinking of the intersection of events in a temporal manner, but this need not be the case. Nor does it necessarily mean that both events are identical in terms of outcome (if they were, it'd just be the same event twice). Intersection of events mean that both events are observed **in the same trial/experiment**. For example, if event $A$ is rolling a $1$ on a die and event $B$ is rolling a $2$, and a trial consists of $3$ rolls, say, then the intersection of events $A$ and $B$ would be rolling at least one of **both** $1$ and $2$. This also goes to demonstrate that "simultaneous" is not the correct description of intersection, because you can't roll two different numbers on a single die at the same time, now can you?

Comment: Thanks for that sir